# Address of Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, memory-address

If the address of the first node of a linked list consisting of an integer and a pointer to the next node is 1000, what will be the address of the second node of the same linked list? Supposing two nodes are allocated contiguously.

Comment: It will be the value of the `next` pointer

Answer (score 0):

The address of the next node is in `next`.

```
(uintptr_t)( ((Node*)1000)->next )
```

We can't give you a specific number from the information you provided because there's no relation between the addresses of the nodes in a linked list. That's the whole point of a linked list: Because the nodes are independently located, you can insert and delete at any point in the list without having to move the rest of the elements.

---

You've edited your question to ask about the addresses of contiguously-allocated objects. By definition, the address of the second will be the address of the first plus the size of the first.

```
(uintptr_t)( ((char*)1000) + sizeof(Node) )
```

We can't give you a specific number from the information you provided because we don't know the size of a `Node`. Even if we knew the size of an "integer" and of a `Node*` in your environment, that wouldn't tell us the size of a `Node`.

Note that it would be *extremely* weird to allocate two nodes of a linked list using one memory allocation (in order to make them contiguously-allocated). Note that two allocations might not produce contiguously-allocated objects (even if allocated one after the other) because of overhead, over-allocation and alignment padding.

Comment: Supposing two nodes are allocated contiguously.

Comment: Added to my answer.